# Scala Defining Custom Type - Type Mismatch Error

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-collections, custom-type

I am doing a basic exercise to understand scala user defined types. Consider the following example:

```
type MyType[T <: AnyVal] = (List[Seq[T]], String, String)
val g: MyType = (List(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), (Seq(5, 6))), "foo", "bar")
```

This fails to compile, with type error:

```
type MyType takes type parameters
[error]     val g: MyType = (List(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), (Seq(5, 6))), "foo", "bar")
```

However, this compiles:

```
type MyType[T <: AnyVal] = (List[Seq[T]], String, String)
val g: MyType[Int] = (List(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), (Seq(5, 6))), "foo", "bar")
```

Is there a way so that Scala can automatically determine the type without needing to specify the exact paramter type? I know for functions we can do the following:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def f1[T](lst: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = {
  lst.toArray
}
```

In which case I do not need to call f1**Int** explicitly, I can just do f1(...) and it works.

Comment: Maybe this can answer you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147001/why-scala-doesnt-infer-type-from-generic-type-parameters?

Comment: Your example with functions doesn't have anything to with your problem. Scala can infer types, but if you are explicit you have to be explicit about everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write

```
val g = (List(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), (Seq(5, 6))), "foo", "bar")
```

and compiler will infer the type. You can check that `g: MyType[Int]` compiles.

Also you can do

```
def TypeOf[F[_ <: AnyVal]] = new PartiallyAppllied[F]
class PartiallyAppllied[F[_ <: AnyVal]] {
  def apply[A <: AnyVal](fa: F[A]) = fa
}

val g = TypeOf[MyType]((List(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), (Seq(5, 6))), "foo", "bar"))

g: MyType[Int]
```

Comment: Exactly. Scala *can* infer the type. But if you want to write it down yourself, you have to write the complete type, not just part of it.

Comment: As for the "counter-example", you cannot declare a function like `def f1[T](lst: List[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag)` either. Both `List` and `ClassTag` need to get their full signature. You can put `List[_]` but not just `List`.